# Fetch details of a ListItem in ListView from MySQL Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview

I have successfully fetched a list from a database and binded it in a ListView. If I select an item from the listView if fetches the correct details of that item. If I select another list item from the listview, it brings the same same data of the previous item selected.

How do I go about solving that? perfectly..

My code is running

Comment: you need to show us some code : )

Comment: You have to pass the correct id of that item to fetch from database..

Comment: Can't say without code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish that process.

use finish(); method after you view the listview details. Otherwise, it will fetch the same value again and again.

Comment: O.K Heres the code, where do i add the method finish?

'code'

Comment: i hope it will work. Use finish(); method after  description.append line.